# angularJS can't add html dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, html

i got an issue that I'm trying to solve but it seems I can't find a proper solution to achieve what I'm trying to do.

I'l try to explain my problem as best as I can: I need to create some tabs heading dynamically depending on the result of an AJAX call, so I don't know in advance how many tabs there will be, I'll post my HTML markup, my controller and what is the result I have in the DOM. I hope I'll be able to explain myself clear enough.

**PART OF THE HTML MARKUP**

```
   <div id="tabPlacer">
   </div>
```

**PART OF ANGULARJS CONTROLLER**

```
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'getNews.json'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.news = data;
        createBase();
        var contFirst=0;
        var contSecond=0;
        for (i=0; i< $scope.news.news[0].allNews.length; i++){
        $scope.bodynews[i] =  $scope.news.news[0].allNews[i].bodyNews;
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            $scope.bodynewsR[contFirst] =  $scope.news.news[0].allNews[i].bodyNews;
            contFirst++;
        }
        else{
            $scope.bodynewsL[contSecond] =  $scope.news.news[0].allNews[i].bodyNews;
            contSecond++;
            }
        }
        $scope.noOfPages =Math.floor($scope.news.news[0].allNews.length / ($scope.itemsPerCol*2));  

        $scope.$watch('currentPage', function() {
            begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerCol);
            end = begin + $scope.itemsPerCol;
            $scope.pagedL = {
                bodynewsL: $scope.bodynewsL.slice(begin, end)
            }
            $scope.pagedR = {
                bodynewsR: $scope.bodynewsR.slice(begin, end)
            }

        });


    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });

    function createBase() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.news.news[0].posizioni.length; i++) {
            // $scope.tabsName[i] = $scope.news.news[0].posizioni[i][i];
            $scope.baseString += "<tab heading='" + $scope.news.news[0].posizioni[i][i] + "' ng-controller='MainController'><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6' id='colonaDx"+ $scope.news.news[0].posizioni[i][i] +"'></div><div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6' id='colonaDx"+ $scope.news.news[0].posizioni[i][i] +"'></div><div id='paginaz"+ $scope.news.news[0].posizioni[i][i] +"'></div></tab>";
        }
        $scope.baseString += "</tabset>";

        $("#tabPlacer").html($scope.baseString);


        }

});
```

**HTML CREATED IN DOM**

```
<div id="tabPlacer">
    <tabset panel-tabs="true" panel-class="panel-grape" data-heading="OTHER NEWS">
        <tab heading="allNews" ng-controller="MainController">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="colonaDxallNews">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="colonaDxallNews">
            </div>
            <div id="paginazallNews">
            </div>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="SecondTab" ng-controller="MainController">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="colonaDxSecondTab">
                </div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="colonaDxSecondTab">
            </div>
            <div id="paginazSecondTab">
            </div>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

So far the problem is that nothing is visualized on the page but if I manually define in the html markup the tabset structure I can see them..any ideas? Thanks very very much in advance.

Comment: Stop now and go learn basics of angularjs. You shouldn't try to add html the old-jquery-way. Directives are meant to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As Cetia said, you don't want to "insert" html into your template in angular. Instead, your situation probably needs [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), which is one of the very basic angular directives you should learn to use.

Basically, you'll want to store the fetched data in a $scope variable, and then use that variable with ng-repeat to display things based on your data. A basic example here:

Controller:

```
$scope.things = [
    {
        name: "Thing1",
        description: "I'm the first thing!"
    },
    {
        name: "Thing2",
        description: "I'm the second thing!"
    }
]
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <tr>
        <td>{{thing.name}}:</td>
        <td>{{thing.description}}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/m8qLdhth/1/